# Behavior of import in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Is it safe to assume that python module is calculated once?
If `module A` contains `CONST_A = json.load(...)` and is imported multiple times in different files of the same program and different threads, will it be calculated/executed just once?
If not, when the `CONST_A` be recalculated? And would the next structure fix it?

```
module CALCULATE_CONST_A
    import json
    CONST_A = json.load(open(...))

module A
    from CALCULATE_CONST_A import CONST_A

further imports of A...
```

Final question: What are the best practices for creating precalculated constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's experiment:

> tbi.py

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

---

> file1.py

```
import tbi
print("This is file1")
```

---

> file2.py

```
import file1
import tbi
print("This is file2")
```

---

And now, when we run `file2`, we see:

```
$ python file2.py
Hello, World!
This is file1
This is file2
```

So the answer to your question is *yes, python modules are executed once only*. If `tbi.py` were executed twice, we would have seen `"Hello World"` printed twice. It's logical, then, to conclude that the attributes of the file are set *the first time that file is imported*.

Furthermore, more experimentation can show you that, if I put a global variable in `tbi`, and both `file1` and `file2` modified it, they would both be modifying the same object. This is visible in a number of built-in packages: for example, changing the value of `sys.stdout` (the file descriptor for standard output, and a global variable specified when the `sys` module is first loaded) changes it for *the entire program*, not just the file that modified it.

---

If you're worried about this sort of thing causing errors, the best thing to do is to not use global variables - instead, use classes and assign them default values when constructed.

Comment: Thanks. Is the calculation made at the start of the program, when execution reaches the file importing module, or at the point when code from the module is actually used?

Comment: The module is loaded at the first time something imports it.